# List of domains used by the Google Maps API Family

Tags: maps, geocoding

I'm looking to find the list of the domains used by the Google Geo Coding API, but I'm not able to find it. The documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/prelaunch_checklist#firewall) is reporting a link to a Salesforce page.

Could anyone help me?

Regards,
Giuseppe.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's up to date, but this is a start http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mapcoverage_filtered.html

Edit: The link above doesn't seem to be up to date. But together with the image in this post, you should get a good idea of all the available domains http://google-latlong.blogspot.nl/2011/08/google-maps-now-available-on-40-new.html.

If you find something better, let me know. I have been looking for this as well for a while now. Maybe the only solution is to just test all tld for countries and see if it works or not.

Comment: I found that spreadsheet (first link) to be a good start, though it is missing at least a few. China, for example: http://ditu.google.cn/